# MATLAB identify adjacient regions in 3D image

Tags: performance, matlab, image-processing, vectorization, adjacency-matrix

I have a 3D image, divided into contiguous regions where each voxel has the same value. The value assigned to this region is unique to the region and serves as a label. The example image below describes the 2D case:

```
     1 1 1 1 2 2 2
     1 1 1 2 2 2 3
Im = 1 4 1 2 2 3 3
     4 4 4 4 3 3 3
     4 4 4 4 3 3 3
```

I want to create a graph describing adjaciency between these regions. In the above case, this would be:

```
    0 1 0 1
A = 1 0 1 1
    0 1 0 1
    1 1 1 0
```

I'm looking for a speedy solution to do this for large 3D images in MATLAB. I came up with a solution that iterates over all regions, which takes `0.05s` per iteration - unfortunately, this will take over half an hour for an image with 32'000 regions. Does anybody now a more elegant way of doing this? I'm posting the current algorithm below:

```
labels = unique(Im); % assuming labels go continuously from 1 to N
A = zeros(labels);

for ii=labels
  % border mask to find neighbourhood
  dil = imdilate( Im==ii, ones(3,3,3) );
  border = dil - (Im==ii);

  neighLabels = unique( Im(border>0) );
  A(ii,neighLabels) = 1;
end
```

`imdilate` is the bottleneck I would like to avoid.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: MEX file? Lighting fast....

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems imdilate is already implemented in a MEX file, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with a solution which is a combination of [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar)'s and [teng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/868736/teng)'s answers, as well as my own modifications and I generalised it to the 2D or 3D case.

To make it more efficient, I should probably pre-allocate the `r` and `c`, but in the meantime, this is the runtime:

- For a **3D** image of dimension `117x159x126` and `32000` separate regions: `0.79s`
- For the above **2D** example: `0.004671s` with this solution, `0.002136s` with Divakar's solution, `0.03995s` with teng's solution.

I haven't tried extending the winner (Divakar) to the 3D case, though!

```
noDims = length(size(Im));
validim = ones(size(Im))>0;
labels = unique(Im);

if noDims == 3
    Im = padarray(Im,[1 1 1],'replicate', 'post');
    shifts = {[-1 0 0] [0 -1 0] [0 0 -1]};
elseif noDims == 2
    Im = padarray(Im,[1 1],'replicate', 'post');
    shifts = {[-1 0] [0 -1]};
end

% get value of the neighbors for each pixel
% by shifting the image in each direction
r=[]; c=[];
for i = 1:numel(shifts)
    tmp = circshift(Im,shifts{i});
    r = [r ; Im(validim)];
    c = [c ; tmp(validim)]; 
end

A = sparse(r,c,ones(size(r)), numel(labels), numel(labels) );
% make symmetric, delete diagonal
A = (A+A')>0;
A(1:size(A,1)+1:end)=0;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great solution. Sparse matrix is the way to go!

Comment: Thanks! The sparse matrix was actually a given, I couldn't store a graph of that size any other way - I left it out in the initial post for clarity's sake because it was not crucial to the method.

Comment: Already +1 this! Exciting stuff really. Get the 3D results too! :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand correctly :) Are you asking for me to report the 3D case? The first result is actually a 3D result (I edited the post to make it a bit clearer).

Comment: Well I meant 3D with `bsxfun` approach? Was that `0.79s` with `bsxfun`? You said you didn't extend `bsxfun` to 3D.

Comment: Assuming I extended it correctly: It's been running for a while now (~5-10mins), so it doesn't seem to scale so well to 3D and larger images.

Comment: Yeah `bsxfun` going to the memory limit it seems, as we were afraid of.

Comment: @Lisa So, I guess stick to the code you have here for 3D cases. But don't forget `bsxfun`, it might come handy! :)

Answer (score 2):

Below is my attempt.

```
 Im = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2;
     1 1 1 2 2 2 3;
     1 4 1 2 2 3 3;
     4 4 4 4 3 3 3;
     4 4 4 4 3 3 3];

 % mark the borders
 validim = zeros(size(Im));
 validim(2:end-1,2:end-1) = 1;

 % get value of the 4-neighbors for each pixel
 % by shifting the images 4 times in each direction
 numNeighbors = 4;
 adj = zeros([prod(size(Im)),numNeighbors]);
 shifts = {[0 1] [0 -1] [1 0] [-1 0]};
 for i = 1:numNeighbors
     tmp = circshift(Im,shifts{i});
     tmp(validim == 0) = nan;
     adj(:,i) = tmp(:);
 end

 % mark neighbors where it does not eq Im
 imDuplicates = repmat(Im(:),[1 numNeighbors]);
 nonequals = adj ~= imDuplicates;
 % neglect the border
 nonequals(isnan(adj)) = 0;     
 % get these neighbor values and the corresponding Im value
 compared = [imDuplicates(nonequals == 1) adj(nonequals == 1)];

 % construct your 'A' % possibly could be more optimized here.
 labels = unique(Im);
 A = zeros(numel(labels));
 for i = 1:size(compared,1)
     A(compared(i,1),compared(i,2)) = 1;
 end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: teng, I used part of your solution for the final working version, thanks! I put my version and the runtime reports in a separate answer, check it out if your interested.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out -

```
Im = padarray(Im,[1 1],'replicate');

labels = unique(Im);
box1 = [-size(Im,1)-1 -size(Im,1) -size(Im,1)+1 -1 1 size(Im,1)-1 size(Im,1) size(Im,1)+1];

mat1 = NaN(numel(labels),numel(labels));
for k2=1:numel(labels)
    a1 = find(Im==k2);
    for k1=1:numel(labels)
        a2 = find(Im==k1);
        t1 = bsxfun(@plus,a1,box1);
        t2 = bsxfun(@eq,t1,permute(a2,[3 2 1]));
        mat1(k2,k1) = any(t2(:));
    end
end
mat1(1:size(mat1,1)+1:end)=0;
```

If it works for you, share with us the runtimes as comparison? Would love to see if the coffee brews any faster than half an hour!

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work, but I'm still trying to figure out how exactly :) I'll report the runtimes!

Comment: Clever, slightly convoluted! I combined parts of yours, @teng 's, and my own modifications, and extended it to the general 2D or 3D case, I'll post the solution and run time (`0.79s` for a high dimensional 3D image!) in a separate answer!

Comment: `bsxfun` brings that "convoluted nature" for sure! Wow, 30 mins to 0.79sec!?

Comment: I guess doing 30'000 dilations isn't the smartest way of going about this :)

Comment: @Lisa That was exactly the problem! Regarding `bsxfun`, it's a memory-intensive approach and most probably uses JIT(just-in-time) compilation, which is exactly why it performs well. But because of the same reason, if you feed it huge data, it might run out-of-memory. That's why I am eagerly waiting for the 3D results :)

Answer (score 0):

@Lisa
Yours reasoning is elegant, though it obviously gives wrong answers for labels on the edges.
Try this simple label matrix:

```
Im =

 1     2     2
 3     3     3
 3     4     4
```

The resulting adjacency matrix , according to your code is:

```
A =

 0     1     1     0
 1     0     1     1
 1     1     0     1
 0     1     1     0
```

which claims an adjacency between labels "2" and "4": obviously wrong. This happens simply because you are reading padded Im labels based on "validim" indices, which now doesn't match the new Im and goes all the way down to the lower borders.